# WPF TextTrimming в DataGridCell

Tags: wpf

Имею DataGrid вида нескольких колонн с заголовками и рядов без заголовков. Хочу чтобы при уменьшении ширины колонны до ширины, меньшей чем длина текста в ячейке, появлялся TextTrimming в виде троеточия. Как это можно сделать через единый стиль?

Comment: <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>?

Comment: @Isaev Да вы что. TextTrimming применяется к textBlock'ам. А мне это надо в клетках Датагрида.

Comment: в wpf не силён, но вроде как раз о датагридах речь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850217/setting-texttrimming-characterellipsis-in-datagrids-cell

Comment: в клетках датагрида TextTrimming для TextBlock с троеточием работает из коробки

Comment: @vitidev Я понял, я тот еще нуб. У меня там DataGridTextColumn'ы и текст в них выводится через биндинг из массива. Я не знаю, может это не textblock'и. Что тогда делать?

Comment: TextTrimming это свойство у TextBlock.  А значит либо явно DataTempate+TextBlock либо стилем для DataGridTextColumn (у которого внутри тот же TextBlock), как указано выше и его в  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>